# Как проверить регулярное выражение на корректность php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, валидация

У пользователя на сайте есть возможность ввести регулярное выражение для валидатора, но как проверить правильно ли он его ввел?

Answer (score 5):

Что понимается под правильно? Синтаксически верно? или получит ли пользователь ожидаемые вхождения? Если синтаксис то preg_match()  вернет false при неверном синтаксисе, если нужна проверить выборку то аналогично прегматч но ожидаем еденицу